# SSRS R2 rendering to excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 2 charts in 2 different tablix on a landscape oriented report.
They are placed side by side.
My problem is when I export the report to excel(and take print preivew) it shows one chart only in one page and second chart goes on next page. Header also breaks and goes half on next page.
It renders properly in word,pdf and html. only in excel it gives me such problem.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the combination of page margins and graph widths that mean that there isn't quite enough room to render both graphs on the same page in preview - however, if it's only whitespace in the graph area that is causing it to exceed the page width, this may be cut when exporting to the other formats.

Try adjusting the left and right page margin settings so that they are smaller, and see if this fixes the problem.